# Handle upDown paging button OnClick event in TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms

is it possible to handle the click events of the `TabControl` paging buttons? The buttons appear when the combined `tabHeader` width exceeds the width of the control.

[image]

I would like to redraw the whole control, if one is clicked.

Comment: I updated the question to show what i mean.

Comment: You may also register on the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `TabControl` for redraw purposes.

Comment: SelectIndexChanged does not fire when a user Clicks one the buttons, since the active tab does not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own event to handle that.  From [TabControl event when scrolling through tab headers](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d190beeb-1b42-413f-9cbc-bf7783562505/tabcontrol-event-when-scrolling-through-tab-headers?forum=csharpgeneral):

```
public class TabConrolEx : TabControl {
  public event ScrollEventHandler Scrolling;

  private const int WM_HSCROLL = 0x114;
  private int oldValue = 0;

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    if (m.Msg == WM_HSCROLL) {
      this.OnScrolling(new ScrollEventArgs(((ScrollEventType)LoWord(m.WParam)), 
        oldValue, HiWord(m.WParam), ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll));
    }
  }

  protected void OnScrolling(ScrollEventArgs e) {
    if (Scrolling != null) {
      Scrolling(this, e);
    }
    if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.EndScroll) {
      oldValue = e.NewValue;
    }
  }

  private int LoWord(IntPtr dWord) {
    return dWord.ToInt32() & 0xffff;
  }

  private int HiWord(IntPtr dWord) {
    if ((dWord.ToInt32() & 0x80000000) == 0x80000000) {
      return (dWord.ToInt32() >> 16);
    } else {
      return (dWord.ToInt32() >> 16) & 0xffff;
    }
  }
}
```

If you use this TabControl in your form, a "Scrolling" event will be available.